# Will the Stack Exchange Data Explorer data for March ’11 be posted before April ‘11?

Tags: support, status-completed, data-explorer

The SEDE FAQ states that the data is updated monthly, and previous months show it happening around the 7th. Now, more than two thirds of March are gone, and we still don't have the March update. Will it be updated before it's April?

Comment: It will but I was flooded with perf work last week, and eek where is my cheese related work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes ... it is up to date now, sorry about the wait.