# Can we get a Stack Exchange Data Explorer update?

Tags: support, data-explorer

The latest [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) update was on March 21. Since it needed two [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83818/will-the-stack-exchange-data-explorer-data-for-march-11-be-posted-before-april) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84376/stack-exchange-data-explorer-was-not-really-updated) last time to get it, I'll ask here: ***can we get a SEDE update, pretty please?*** Could them updates be monthly, pretty pretty please?

Comment: FTR, it may take longer this time around at least in part due to database schema changes, which broke some of the import scripts. (I noticed this when I was looking at it earlier today.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data was updated to May 7–9, except for WebApps Meta (April 19). Thanks!

Comment: The *date* was updated, but I'm still seeing old *data*. I guess it's the same problem as [last time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84376/stack-exchange-data-explorer-was-not-really-updated).

Comment: And now it really is up-to-date. Thanks at whoever it was.

Comment: @RegDwight: see [there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91641/pretty-pretty-please-can-you-update-the-sede-data-not-just-the-date)